# Extracting numeric portion from a character in the Data Frame

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the numeric portion of this string from DF$Numbers like changing W12K32 to 1232

Current DF

```
  Name Numbers
1 Alex  W12K32
2  Tom S12WE23
3 Eric   T1243
```

Desired Output

```
  Name Numbers
1 Alex    1232
2  Tom    1223
3 Eric    1243
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub` and strip off all non numeric characters:

```
df$Numbers <- gsub("\\D+", "", df$Numbers)
df

  Name Numbers
1 Alex    1232
2  Tom    1223
3 Eric    1243
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("Alex", "Tom", "Eric"), Numbers=c("W12K32", "S12WE23", "T1243"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: @RonakShah I just got a bunch of hats.  I think one of them is answer first.