# Extracting numerical portion of string occurring in the entire data frame

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe

I have a data set which is read into a dataframe as characters. The characters have numerical portions, and some include a "/T". For example:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("237.7", "191.8", "95.4/T", "48.1"), 
                 col2 = c("234.3", "766.4/T", "167.6/T", "401.6"))
> df
    col1    col2
1  237.7   234.3
2  191.8 766.4/T
3 95.4/T 167.6/T
4   48.1   401.6
```

What command can I use to identify the rows and columns in the dataframe which contain data with "/T"?
The following will clearly not work:

```
which(df == "/T", arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Also, I want to extract only the numerical portion of the data from the entire dataframe, or remove all "/T". My actual example has far more columns and rows than the example I provide above. I have seen the following examples in Stack Overflow:

[Extracting decimal numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252663/extracting-decimal-numbers-from-a-string)

[Extracting numeric portion from a character in the Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317103/extracting-numeric-portion-from-a-character-in-the-data-frame)

The above links provide solutions to vectors or a column of the data frame. How can I generalize these solutions to go systemically throughout the entire dataframe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your data looks like and how you are using it, there are multiple ways to address this.

If you need to identify which rows/columns contain "/T", you could do something like this (using the dplyr package's `mutate` function along with base R's `grepl` and `gsub`).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    col1_check = ifelse(grepl("/T", col1), "problem", "okay"), 
    col2_check = ifelse(grepl("/T", col2), "problem", "okay"), 
    col1_clean = gsub("/T", "", col1), 
    col2_clean = gsub("/T", "", col2)
    )
```

Which results in this output:

```
    col1    col2 col1_check col2_check col1_clean col2_clean
1  237.7   234.3       okay       okay      237.7      234.3
2  191.8 766.4/T       okay    problem      191.8      766.4
3 95.4/T 167.6/T    problem    problem       95.4      167.6
4   48.1   401.6       okay       okay       48.1      401.6
```

If you just need to remove the "/T" portion, you can use dplyr's `mutate_at` function with `gsub` (applied to whatever columns you want to fix):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(col1, col2), list(~gsub("/T", "", .)))
```

And if you need to extract only the numeric elements and the period (say you have other symbols than just "/T"), you can use the stringr package's `str_extract` function with some regex:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(col1, col2), list(~str_extract(., "[0-9.]+")))
```